# Finding the complementary space to the image of an injective map

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be linear spaces and let $S:X\rightarrow Y$ and $T:Y\rightarrow X$ linear maps such that $T\circ S=id_X$. We can show that $S$ is injective and therefore it restricts to an isomorphism in $S:X\rightarrow S(X)\subseteq Y$. I wanted to find a complementary subspace $N\subseteq Y$, that is, a subspace such that $Y=S(X)\oplus N$. I tried choosing $N=\ker T$, but I'm still left with the issue of taking an arbitrary $y\in Y$ such that $y=Sx+z$ where $z\in N$. If $N=\ker T$, then $Ty=TS(x)=x$ but I'm left with the portion of $Y$ that is not $S(X)$, if that makes sense. $S$ is invertible in $S(X)$ but not globally so I'm not sure this works.

I've seen this claimed in the context of continuous linear maps between normed spaces, but I believe this is a purely linear algebraic property, which might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $V$ is a subspace of $U$. Then take a basis $B$ of $V$. Extend this to a basis $B'$ of $U$. Then let $N = span(B - B')$. Then $U = V \oplus N$. So it's always possible to find a complementary subspace.

This is because every independent set is a subset of a basis.

In your case, $ker(T)$ works. For suppose we have $x \in ker(T) \cap Im(S)$. Write $x = S(y)$. Then we have $0 = T(x) = T(S(y)) = y$. Then $x = 0$. And now consider an arbitrary $z \in Y$. Then write $z = (z - S(T(z))) + S(T(z))$. We see that $S(T(z)) \in Im(S)$, and we see that $T(z - S(T(z))) = T(z) - T(S(T(z))) = T(z) - T(z) = 0$, so $z - S(T(z)) \in ker(T)$.

Comment: Very good. I haven't thought about using $S\circ T$ to write the complementary term of the direct sum. About your first argument with basis, is it still true when $V$ is not finite-dimensional?

Comment: @園田海未 Yes. You can use Zorn's lemma to show that every independent subset $U$ of a vector space $V$ extends to a basis, since the collection of all independent subsets of $V$ which contain $U$ forms a partial order under $\subseteq$ and every chain has an upper bound.